# Calling C++ Method from Assembly with Parameters and Return Value

Tags: c++, assembly, parameters, x86, return-value

So I've asked this before but with significantly less detail. The question title accurately describes the problem: I have a method in C++ that I am trying to call from assembly (x86) that has both parameters and a return value. I have a rough understanding, at best, of assembly and a fairly solid understanding of C++ (otherwise I would not have undertaken this problem). Here's what I have as far as code goes:

```
// methodAddr is a pointer to the method address
void* methodAddr = method->Address;

// buffer is an int array of parameter values. The parameters can be anything (of any type)
// but are copied into an int array so they can be pushed onto the stack in reverse order
// 4 bytes at a time (as in push (int)). I know there's an issue here that is irrelevent to my baseline testing, in that if any parameter is over 4 bytes it will be broken and
// reversed (which is not good) but for basic testing this isn't an issue, so overlook this.
for (int index = bufferElementCount - 1; index >= 0; index--)
{
    int val = buffer[index];

    __asm
    {
        push val
    }
}

int returnValueCount = 0;

// if there is a return value, allocate some space for it and push that onto the stack after
// the parameters have been pushed on
if (method->HasReturnValue)
{
    *returnSize = method->ReturnValueSize;
    outVal = new char[*returnSize];
    returnValueCount = (*returnSize / 4) + (*returnSize % 4 != 0 ? 1 : 0);
    memset(outVal, 0, *returnSize);

    for (int index = returnValueCount - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        char* addr = ((char*)outVal) + (index * 4);

        __asm
        {
            push addr
        }
    }
}

// calculate the stack pointer offset so after the call we can pop the parameters and return value
int espOffset = (bufferElementCount + returnValueCount) * 4;

// call the method
__asm
{
    call methodAddr;
    add esp, espOffset
};
```

For my basic testing I am using a method with the following signature:

```
Person MyMethod3( int, char, int );
```

The problem is this: when omit the return value from the method signature, all of the parameter values are properly passed. But when I leave the method as is, the parameter data that is passed is incorrect but the value returned is correct. So my question, obviously, is what is wrong? I've tried pushing the return value space onto the stack before the parameters. The person structure is as follows:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Text Name;
    int Age;
    float Cash;
    ICollection<Person*>* Friends;
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with the November 2013 CTP compiler for C++, targeting x86.

As it relates to disassembly, this is the straight method call:

```
int one = 876;
char two = 'X';
int three = 9738;

Person p = MyMethod3(one, two, three);
```

And here is the disassembly for that:

```
00CB0A20  mov         dword ptr [one],36Ch  
    char two = 'X';
00CB0A27  mov         byte ptr [two],58h  
    int three = 9738;
00CB0A2B  mov         dword ptr [three],260Ah  
    Person p = MyMethod3(one, two, three);
00CB0A32  push        10h  
00CB0A34  lea         ecx,[p]  
00CB0A37  call        Person::__autoclassinit2 (0C6AA2Ch)  
00CB0A3C  mov         eax,dword ptr [three]  
00CB0A3F  push        eax  
00CB0A40  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [two]  
00CB0A44  push        ecx  
00CB0A45  mov         edx,dword ptr [one]  
00CB0A48  push        edx  
00CB0A49  lea         eax,[p]  
00CB0A4C  push        eax  
00CB0A4D  call        MyMethod3 (0C6B783h)  
00CB0A52  add         esp,10h  
00CB0A55  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0
```

My interpretation of this is as follows:
Execute the assignments to the local variables. Then create the output register. Then put the parameters in a particular register (the order here happens to be `eax`, `ecx`, and `edx`, which makes sense (`eax` and `ebx` are for one, `ecx` is for two, and `edx` and some other register for the last parameter?)). Then call `LEA` (load-effective address) which I don't understand but have understood to be a `MOV`. Then it calls the method with an address as the parameter? And then moves the stack pointer to pop the parameters and return value.

Any further explanation is appreciated, as I'm sure my understanding here is somewhat flawed.

Comment: It sounds like the calling convention is, for some reason, changing between the two versions of the method. Have you tried forcing it to use a specific one?

Comment: Which platform? Which ABI? Which calling convention? Have you remembered to pass the `this` pointer?

Comment: The calling convention the method was specified with will most likely be `stdcall` or `thiscall`. I have a way of identifying the difference between the two, but I'm only testing the traditional `stdcall`. The problem is that the method being called can be anything: it can have any number of parameters of any type, and may or may not have a return value.

Comment: You already have a reference implementation: the compiler. Write the call in C++, compile it, then look at what the compiler did. You'll see that it is more complicated than what you have. In fact what you want is not possible because the compiler can use optimizations which are tantamount to a custom calling convention.

Comment: I've tried looking at the disassembly, but it does some very complex stuff that that involves LEA and other terms I'm not sure of. I'll post the DA.

Comment: Do you intentionally pass back a class? Because this would involve instantiating new object with calling constructor, etc. and possibly copying it. Or do you want to pass back a pointer?

Comment: I'm trying to create a generic caller, and sometimes people (poorly or unintentionally) pass back by value, which I need to account for. I simply need to be able to handle any type of return value.